# dynamic cmd.Cmd tab-completion

Tags: python, command-line

I try to use [Cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.cmdloop) , but instead of adding all functions/commands separately, I want it to read functionnames from a dictionary and add them dynamically.
The `preloop` should add functions  `do_aa`, `complete_aa`, `do_bb` and `complete_bb`.
The commands are taken from a dictionary, and added using `setattr`

```
import cmd

class C(cmd.Cmd):

    commands = {'aa': ['aa1', 'aa2'],
                'bb': ['bb1', 'bb2']}

    def preloop(self):
        for k, v in self.commands.items():
            self.k = k
            setattr(C, 'do_' + k, k)
            setattr(C, 'complete_' + k, self.complete_)

    def complete_(self, text, line, start_index, end_index):
        if text:
            return [
                command for command in self.commands[self.k]
                if command.startswith(text)
            ]
        else:
            return self.commands[self.k]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    C().cmdloop()
```

The problem is that the autocomplete does not actually get the correct second-level commands:

```
(Cmd) aa 
bb1  bb2  # should be aa1 aa2
(Cmd) bb
bb1  bb2
```

Why is this happening, and how can this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

Your script does not work with `Python 3.8.10` probably because of this line

```
setattr(C, 'do_' + k, k)
```

`k` is not a method. By the way, the mistake is in this line:

```
for k, v in self.commands.items():
     self.k = k  # <--
```

You are continuously reassigning `self.k` until the last key of the `commands` dictionary, that is `bb`. Later, the `complete_` method is always evaluated as `self.commands['bb']`. Here is a possible working version:

```
import cmd

class C(cmd.Cmd):

    commands = {
            'aa': ['aa1', 'aa2'],
            'bb': ['bb1', 'bb2']
        }
        
    def monad_print(self, *args):
        print(args)

    def preloop(self):
        for k, v in self.commands.items():
            setattr(C, 'do_' + k, lambda self, arg, k=k: self.monad_print(k, arg))
            setattr(C, 'complete_' + k, self.complete_)

    def complete_(self, text, line, start_index, end_index):
        command = line.split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0]
        if text:
            return [
                command for command in self.commands[command]
                if command.startswith(text)
            ]
        else:
            return self.commands[command]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    C().cmdloop()
```

The only difference is that the command is now taken from the entire read-line, in particular the first token of `str.split()`.